# Calling previous switch in Java

Tags: java

I'm making a simple command line system where the user is supposed to be able to choose what they want to do. Therefore I've made a switch that takes a number as input and outputs whatever I choose, although I have now clue on how to return the user to the place where they can input again.
Let's say two of the cases looks like this:

```
    case 6:
          System.out.println("----- List of available Systems: ----- ");       
          break;
     default:
          System.out.println("You pressed a non-existing number. Please try again.");
          break;
        }
```

Now if the user (me) types any number above 6 it goes to the default and stops there. Is there anyway to make it jump back to the first "Menu" that asks for input?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: How about a loop

Comment: You are screaming for `goto`. Also, have you thought about using recursive functions, so that you can just call the function again and do some IF-ELSE based flow control?

Comment: A loop might do it. Although I'm not sure how to use the loop in a switch.
I'll search for goto.

Comment: I would suggest not doing either thing @ha9u63ar has said. There is no goto functionality implemented in Java (though the keyword is there), and recursion is an awful suggestion for this.

Comment: Could you provide more details on the control flow of your program, though most likely you'll end up needing to put a loop somewhere.

Comment: Just wrap it in a loop set the value you wish to go to, break.

Comment: @Kon If I can't do either of those things, what can I do? :/

Comment: @Colour How about a loop

Comment: @Kon LOL :D You better provide him a example or he will be stucked here forever =)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about something more verbal..

```
int myno;
Scanner scanner  =new Scanner(System.in);
boolean exit = false;
while(!exit){

    System.out.println("1. Menu 1");//Modify your menu
    System.out.println("2. Menu 2");
    System.out.println("3. Menu 3");
    System.out.println("4. Menu 4");
    System.out.println("5. Menu 5");
    System.out.println("6. Menu 6");

    myno = scanner.nextInt();

    switch(myno){
    case 1 :
        //do something
        break;
    case 2 :
        //do something
        break;
    case 3 :
        //do something
        break;                     //add for remaining cases
    case 7 :
        exit = true;//for exit
        break;  

    default :
        // do something   //set exit = true if you what to end the program for other inputs
    }
}
```

try this

Comment: @Colour see my updated answer seems this is what you are looking for..?

Comment: I'll check it out :).

Comment: This worked out for me! 
Thanks a lot @theRoot. Is there any way of "calling" the switch at any other time? Like if you are in a completely different "menu" and want to go back to the first menu?

Answer (score 6):

You can wrap it in a loop, e.g. a `while`:

```
while (var < 1 || var > 6) {
    switch(var) {
        ...
    }
}
```

However, this way, you need to make sure, that you won't be stuck in an infinite loop. This can be solved, e.g. by using a label:

```
end: while (var < 1 || var > 6) {
    switch (var) {
        case 1:
            // do something
            break end;
        ...
        default:
            System.out.println("Please try again.");
            break;
    }
}
```

This way, the `break` statements will break out of the `while` loop. Java labels are basically a *very limited* version of `goto`.

Comment: Just make sure you set it to a value outside of the condition when you finish, or you'll get an infinite loop.

Comment: Or simply break out using a label.

Comment: Not sure if I am doing anything wrong, but this doesn't seem to work as it just spams Please try again.

Comment: I think you want use a do/while loop. In the loop you've proposed, the only way to enter the loop is to input an "invalid" value and therefore all the non-default cases will never be true.  Also, your loop would only be infinite if the user continued to input invalid values, so I don't think the label is necessary, as long as you continue to ask for user input inside the loop before the switch statement

Comment: @Colour are you asking for user input inside your loop?